# F# how to return have value a tuple or null

Tags: f#

```
    let retVal =
      if reader.Read() then
        (reader.GetString(0), getBytesData reader 1, reader.GetDateTime(2))
      else
        null
```

F# don't allow null to returned

**How can i have value return as a tuple or a null?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not that F# does not allow you to return null.

It is because then part and else part have different types.

You can use [Option type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx).

```
let retVal =
  if reader.Read() then
    Some (reader.GetString(0), getBytesData reader 1, reader.GetDateTime(2))
  else
    None
```

when you use `retVal`, you use pattern matching:

```
match retVal with
| Some v -> ...
| None -> // null case
```

Answer (score 8):

To add some additional information to the Yin Zhu's answer, the situation with `null` value in the F# language is following:

- F# types such as tuples (e.g. `int * int`), which is exactly your case don't have `null` as a valid value, so you cannot use `null` in this case (other such types are function values e.g. `int -> int`, lists and most of the F# library types)
- Types from the .NET framework can have `null` value, so you can for example write:

  ```
  let (rnd:Random) = null
  ```

  This isn't idiomatic F# style, but it is allowed.
- If you define your own F# type, it won't automatically allow you to use `null` as a valid value of the type (which follows the goal to minimize the use of `null` in F#). However, you can explicitly allow this:

  ```
  [<AllowNullLiteral>]
  type MyType = ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

To further clarify, I copy my answer from [How do you return a null Tuple from f# to c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748577) which was closed as a duplicate of this question:

If you need it to interop with C#, you can use `Unchecked.Defaultof` like so:

```
let retVal =
  if reader.Read() then
    (reader.GetString(0), getBytesData reader 1, reader.GetDateTime(2))
  else
    Unchecked.Defaultof<_>
```

However, using null values is strongly discouraged in F#, and if interoperability is not your main concern, using an option is much more natural:

```
let retVal =
  if reader.Read() then
    Some (reader.GetString(0), getBytesData reader 1, reader.GetDateTime(2))
  else
    None
```