# How do you return a null Tuple from f# to c#?

Tags: c#, f#, null, tuples

I have this type-correct C# function:

```
static System.Tuple<int,int> f(int n) { 
  switch (n) { 
    case 0: return null;
    default: return System.Tuple.Create(n,n+1);
  }
}
```

I try to re-implement it in F#:

```
let f = function 
| 0 -> null 
| n -> System.Tuple.Create(n, n+1)
```

Type-checker disagrees, though:

```
error FS0001: The type '('a * 'b)' does not have 'null' as a proper value.
```

How do I re-implement the original C# function `f` in F#?

Note that while this looks like the question “how do I return null in F#” (answer: don’t, use Option) we are asking the slightly different “how do we return null from F# *for C# consumers*” (can’t use Option, helpful answer below).

Comment: You can return `Unchecked.defaultof<_>` which for a ref tuple is `null`.

Comment: That's how F# enforses you not to use `null`. I would suggest instead of reimplementing C# code use `Option` here and return `None` or `Some (n, n+1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to interop with C#, you can use `Unchecked.Defaultof` like so:

```
let f = function
    | 0 -> Unchecked.Defaultof<_>
    | n -> (n, n + 1)
```

However, using null values is strongly discouraged in F#, and if interoperability is not your main concern, using an option is much more natural:

```
let f = function
    | 0 -> None
    | n -> Some (n, n + 1)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This question was closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983242/f-how-to-return-have-value-a-tuple-or-null, but the answers to that question all say “just use Option”. Can I suggest you repeat your answer here over at that question so that people will find it in the future?